# Send integer from client to server Java

Tags: java, sockets, http, server, client

Good evening, i got this server here,

**httpServer**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class httpServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
    //NimServer nimserver = new NimServer(32778);
    //nimserver.serve();

}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0); 
    int theValue = atomicInteger.get(); 
    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        final String response;

        final String requestMethod = t.getRequestMethod();
        if ("GET".equals(requestMethod)) {
            response = String.format("Besuche: %d%n", atomicInteger.addAndGet(1));
        }
        else if ("POST".equals(requestMethod)) {
            atomicInteger.set(0);
            response = "Reset to 0";

        }
        else {
            throw new IOException("Unsupported method");
        }

        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        final OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
}
```

and this Client here

**httpClient**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class httpClient {

static int clientno = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

System.out.println(clientno);

URL test = new URL("http://localhost:8000/test");
HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) test.openConnection();
connect.setRequestMethod("POST");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;







while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();

}
}
```

Now i want to send the *int clientno* from the client to the server and the server should count it up like ++ and send it back to the client. I read alot about Dataoutputstream but there are always sockets included. Is it possible to do it without sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side you in the handler for "POST" you have to invoke `t.getRequestBody()` - this will give you client input. Either using `BufferedReader` (if text based - `Integer.valueOf(stream.readLine())`) or `DataInputStream` (if binary based - `stream.readInt()`) you can read the number. Similarly by `t.getResponseBody()` you get the output to client and write the number in similar way.

For the client the `HttpURLConnection` has `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` to which you need to write `clientNumber` similarly how you do in server.

Comment: im trying to implement this in my code but it doesnt seem to work. can you give me and example how this might look?

Comment: `new DataOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream ()).writeInt(clientNo)` and on the server `clientNo = new DataInputStream(t.getRequestBody()).rreadInt()`, do whatever you want and rrspond with `new DataOutputStream(t.getResponseBody()).writeInt(responseInt)`

Comment: sorry this is not working for me im too stupid to get i right.